# Is it possible to order by class type in NHibnernate IQueryable

Tags: c#, nhibernate, iqueryable, linq-to-nhibernate

It is possible to order by class type in HQL and ICriteria queries using the special keyword class.

```
criteria.AddOrder("s.class", true);
```

Can this keyword be used in an IQueryable OrderBy?  This seems to only except propery expressions and .GetType() is not supported.

Comment: It appears HQL `class` special property of base entities is deprecated on Hibernate side, in favor of HQL function `type(entityAlias)`. See this [doc info notice](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-entity-type-exp). But I have not found any information on what is NHibernate stance on that subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Quick&Dirty suggestion

A dirty hack may work. In my experience, linq2NH does translate queryables to `HQL` without much checks (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34287778/1178314) for an example case in its 'trick' sample code). So you may add a dummy and not mapped `public virtual string @class { get; set; }` property on your base entity then order by it.

```cs
session.Query<YourBaseEntityType>().OrderBy(e => e.@class);
```

Test it, it is likely it would be translated 'bluntly' to a working `HQL` query. Of course, it is ugly, may break at any NH version upgrade, ...

(The `@` is required because `class` is a reserved word in C#. Prefixing with `@` tells the compiler it is just a name, not the `class` keyword.)

## Cleaner suggestion

A cleaner way would be to [extend](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.fr/2010/07/nhibernate-linq-provider-extension.html) linq2NH for supporting a `Class()` method on your entities. (Blog post found on [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11860887/1178314). Edit: here is another interesting [implementation example on SO](/a/21060461/1178314), and here is a [list of links](/a/11469134/1178314) which provides much more information on [linq-to-nhibernate](/questions/tagged/linq-to-nhibernate) extensibility.)

Adapting linked above 'extend' blog post to your case, it should be something like following steps.

First, you need an extension method usable on your entities. Something like:

```cs
public static class YourLinqExtensions
{
    public static string Class(this YourEntityBaseClass source)
    { 
        // .Net runtime implementation just in case, useless in linq2nhib case
        return source == null ? null : source.GetType().Name;
    }
}
```

Then, implements its `HQL` translation:

```cs
public class ClassGenerator : NHibernate.Linq.Functions.BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod
{
    public ClassGenerator()
    {
        SupportedMethods = new[]
        {
            NHibernate.Linq.ReflectionHelper.GetMethod(
                () => YourLinqExtensions.Class(null))
        };
    }

    public override NHibernate.Hql.Ast.HqlTreeNode BuildHql(MethodInfo method, 
        Expression targetObject,
        ReadOnlyCollection<Expression> arguments,
        NHibernate.Hql.Ast.HqlTreeBuilder treeBuilder,
        NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.IHqlExpressionVisitor visitor)
    {
        return treeBuilder.Dot(
            // using NHibernate.Hql.Ast; required for .AsExpression() to be found
            // at compile time.
            visitor.Visit(arguments[0]).AsExpression(),
            // Below 'Class' method is not 'YourLinqExtensions.Class' extension
            // method. It is natively available on HqlTreeBuilder.
            treeBuilder.Class());
    }
}
```

Extend the default linq2NH registry with your generator:

```cs
public class YourLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry:
    NHibernate.Linq.Functions.DefaultLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry
{
    public YourLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry()
    {
        // using NHibernate.Linq.Functions; required for .Merge() to be found
        // at compile time.
        this.Merge(new ClassGenerator());
    }
}
```

And configure NH to use your new registry. With hibernate.cfg.xml, it should be something like adding following `property` node under `session-factory` node:

```xml
<property name="linqtohql.generatorsregistry">YourNameSpace.YourLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry, YourAssemblyName</property>
```

Usage:

```cs
session.Query<YourBaseEntityType>().OrderBy(e => e.Class());
```

(With the way I have elaborated all of this, it should at least compile, but it is fully untested. Edit: now it is tested.)

Comment: Would be nice to be sure that it is tested and working.. but as a concept you did a great job here...

Comment: The dirty suggestion is working.  I have not been able to get the cleaner suggestion working.  It is generating a NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException "A recognition error occurred."  I am using NHibernate 4.0.0.4000

Comment: @RadimKöhler, yes I agree, answers should be tested. But I have no dev env at home (not even MS Windows indeed), and doing that from work is not what I am paid for. So on unanswered questions, giving some untested suggestions may still help.

Comment: @Skippy, my `BuildHql` implementation was wrong. I was wondering how it was inferring on what to apply `class`. It was not able to do that. I have now added the `Dot` construct in `BuildHql` which allows to explicit this. (And this time, tested (but I am way out of office normal hours, though still there).) It was quite a great deal of fiddling, I was unable to find relevant doc about all that.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Frédéric.  I have confirmed the cleaner suggestion has solved my question.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, a sorting expression that is based upon a comparison to a specific type should work. For example (forgive the VB.NET):

```
Dim o = Session.Query(Of Animal).OrderBy(Function(x) If(TypeOf x Is Cat, 1, 2)).ToList()
```

Comment: While I was at this subject, I have tested with skepticism the c# translation of your suggestion. But it works indeed. `session.Query<YourBaseEntityType>().OrderBy(e => e is SomeChildClass ? 1 : 2);`